# Joomla store files in database

Tags: joomla

I am using Joomla 2.5

I want to store user uploaded content (like images or general files) in the database instead of in the server.

Is there any existing setting which can be used to do this by default?

Note: I am interested in the user uploaded files. Joomla's own files can stay on the server or on in the database, either is fine by me.

Answer (score 1):

The database doesn't store things like images, its stored information. Images and so on are always stored on the server. The only thing you could do is once an image is uploaded to the server, it stored information about it such as the format, dimensions etc in the database. Would be a good idea to use a gallery such as [Phoca Gallery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/photo-gallery/3150) or [JoomGallery](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/photo-gallery/5481). More can be found [here.](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/photo-gallery)

If you are looking for a general file uploader then feel free to use my [SWFUpload Component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/file-management/21091) which is only for uploading in the admin backend however is a very simple component therefore will be easy to integrate into other components should you need to.